# In what format I should share a semi complete business & technical innovative idea in enterprise

Tags: research-process

**Question**

Does this fit a Yellow paper or a Whitepaper or other kind of document?

**Context:**

*What is my document about ?*

I am developing an idea, out of a business need. It is not an algorithm or a 100% technical specification to solve the problem, it can accept a wide range of solutions. To put you in context, it is about:
"Evolving ETLs with future business specifications". For this, I wrote a document presenting many ideas, a study of the existing techniques and technologies. Along the lines, and in the first section of the document, I exposed the problem and how I see the *new* solution. Therefore technically it is not 100% specified, because I have not 100% the knowledge and experience nor I have the time to develop more (this is why I want to throw the document).

*Why do I write this document ?*

As you know all, in a professional environment (without necessarily a research subdivision), other developers are not just there to discuss ideas. Even seeking knowledge (at least in my space) is not easy. Simply asking for a review from other say experimented developers in the same field of study also can be out of scope, they are already working on on-running products and not necessarily looking for innovation (let's say it, without $$ or reputations).

The core purpose of the document is to:

1. Save my work, even when not 100% specified.
2. Share knowledge and in a way seek indirectly help and get the attention of more experimented peers hiding somewhere.
3. Prove some motivation.
4. Very probably, it can be a base for new products around the idea.
5. Push others to thinking (like some ppt presentation I saw in IT late meetings, some presentation with a lot of question marks "??")

Is this what we call a Yellow paper ?

Answer (score 1):

To share new enterprise ideas, you should follow the procedure defined by your enterprise. I suspect a white paper would be suitable, since a yellow paper may reveal too many technical details that your enterprise might want to patent.

Comment: I am not sure about the terms, all whitepaper I saw were like very broad, roadmap like or a way of thinking, philosophical way of work and so..

Comment: Yellow paper, it is new to me, I read that in academic world, in research, A yellow paper is a document containing research that has not yet been formally accepted or published in an academic journal. It is synonymous to the more widely used term preprint.[wikipedia] so it a better fit I think... If the enterprise decide to patent, then I think I will be lucky ?!

Comment: @Curcuma_ The enterprise should surely patent if they are interested.